# “I could have loved you”

Tags: meaning, grammar, tenses, have, could

What does “I could have loved you” mean? And what is the tense of that sentence? Is it a clause or a sentence? I found one if-clause sentence on google “If you had let me, I could have loved you.”, could I use “I could have loved you” alone without using “If you had let me,...”? Can it still be meaningful?

Comment: Sentences **are** clauses. Syntactically, the modal auxiliary verb "could" is a past tense form, so "I could have loved you" is a past tense clause. Note also that "have loved you" is a perfect tense clause, and the perfect is of course a past tense, so the the clause is doubly past tense.

Answer (score 1):

> What does “I could have loved you” mean?

It means

"There was a time/occasion (in the past) when the possibility of my being able to love you existed." However, it carries the implication that the possibility was not realised and something prevented this and the speaker did not commence to love the listener.

It therefore encompasses the idea of a theoretical situation - something that did not happen in the past, but which, if it had happened, would have changed the present. This is sometimes known as "irrealis". It does not have a true tense as it did not happen - however, it references the past.

The "tense" of the whole sentence is governed by the main clause of the paraphrase "There **was** a time/occasion".

"when the possibility of my being able to love you existed." is adjectival and modifies "time".

The net result is that when spoken "I could have loved you" has a hidden/unspoken "if clause".

Comment: +1 I agree completely. "Had circumstances been different, I would have loved you"

Comment: "If" is a preposition so conditional adjuncts are PPs not clauses. Syntactically, the matrix clause is in the perfect tense, which is of course a past tense. Further, the matrix verb is the preterite "could". You're trying to analyse a paraphrase of the OP's example, which is inappropriate.

Comment: Just because the clause is probably the apodosis of a conditional construction doesn't change the way it is analysed. "Could" is a past tense form, which here has a perfect clause (also past tense) as its complement. The fact that there's no primary tense doesn't mean it's not past tense.

Comment: "There was a time/occasion (in the past) when the possibility of my being able to love you existed." Isn't that a line from a famous song? [:)]

Comment: Yes, this is the song’s title of Frankie Valli.

Comment: FWIW, this phrase does not say anything AT ALL about the situation in the present, only the situation in the past. For example: "Back then I could have loved you but I was scared. Today, though, I have shaken off my fear and I do love you."